# 14.04 resumes to black screen, no response

Tags: gnome, 14.04, suspend

My laptop was working great with 13.10, no problems with suspend/resume.

However, after the upgrade to 14.04, I started having issues resuming from suspend. The screen would be completely black, no keyboard or mouse input would have any effect (including <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F7</kbd>). Sometimes it would work fine but most of the time it didn't work, and I couldn't find any pattern. I had to do a hard reboot.

My laptop:

Dell Inspiron 1525
Graphics: Intel GM965/GL960
Ubuntu Gnome 14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read some posts mentioning that USB keyboard and mouse could be related. After some experimenting, I finally found a solution:

- Before suspending the laptop, I unplug my mouse (it's wireless, so I
  just remove the receiver)
- Once it is suspended, I put the receiver back in
- Resuming with the receiver inserted works

I probably didn't try all possible combinations but this has reliably worked for me.